# What devices do /sys/class/bdi/ settings correspond to

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, devices

[`/sys/class/bdi`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-class-bdi) has settings for things like readahead and dirty page ratios for devices.  It is organized by bdi identifier, which is the major:minor device number or the `st_dev` value set by the file system.  My `/sys/class/bdi` contains:

```
$ ls /sys/class/bdi/
0:184  0:342  0:345  0:374  0:39  0:40  0:404  0:405  0:42  253:0  253:1  7:0  7:1  8:0  8:16  8:32  default
```

My question is: how do I know what devices/file systems the `0:` entries correspond to?  The entries with non-zero major numbers are devices listed in e.g. `/proc/devices`, but I can't figure out what the other entries are for.

Comment: not posting an answer as i barely know about the kernel, but check the `bdi_register` function at `mm/backing-dev.c`, and according to https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/devices.txt `0:x` devices are unnamed devices. on my machine i have a `/sys/class/bdi/0:49` symlink, which turned out to be a FUSE mount, found with the command `mount -l | awk '{ print $3 }' | xargs stat`

Comment: So you have a mountpoint that when you `stat` it the Device field says `31h/49d`?  I tried stat'ing all of my  mount points but none of the Device fields match the devices listed in `/sys/class/bdi`.

Answer (score 0):

If you truly need to do the detection of random BDI idenfier from the virtual directory `/sys/class/bdi`, I'd recommend doing something like

```
$ sudo find /sys -type l -exec ls -la {} + | grep -E '(bdi|block)/8:32'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 20 12:33 /sys/class/bdi/8:32 -> ../../devices/virtual/bdi/8:32
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 20 12:33 /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata3/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sdc/bdi -> ../../../../../../../../virtual/bdi/8:32
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 20 12:33 /sys/devices/virtual/bdi/8:32/subsystem -> ../../../../class/bdi
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  0 Aug 20 12:33 /sys/dev/block/8:32 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata3/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sdc
```

if the identifier you want to know about is `8:32`. However, if you already know that the BDI correspoinds to block device, you can simply read the links in virtual directory `/sys/dev/block`. For example

```
$ readlink /sys/dev/block/8:32
../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata3/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sdc
```

which should give you pretty good understanding what device that is. In this example case, it's the device `sdc` connected to third ATA interface.

However, if you're interested in BDI settings for any given device, you can simply read the virtual files in virtual directory, for example:

```
$ grep . /sys/block/sda/bdi/*
/sys/block/sda/bdi/max_ratio:40
/sys/block/sda/bdi/min_ratio:0
grep: /sys/block/sda/bdi/power: Is a directory
/sys/block/sda/bdi/read_ahead_kb:128
/sys/block/sda/bdi/stable_pages_required:0
grep: /sys/block/sda/bdi/subsystem: Is a directory
```

I guess that this could work for most cases, too:

```
$ readlink /sys/dev/*/8:32
../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata3/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sdc
```

which uses shell wild card expansion to figure out the correct device class automatically.